# Constrained extremum examples in 3 dimensional space

Tags: real-analysis

My university professor asked me to make some visual examples of constrained extremum for real analysis course.

I think that the easiest example to showcase constrained extremum is function $ f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2 $ with constraint $ x = 0 $ (or with $ y = 0 $).

Do you know any interesting examples of constrained extrema in 3-dimensional space?

Answer (score 1):

Example: Let $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ and $K=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2=2, x+z=1\}.$

Show that $K$ is compact and find $\max f(K)$ and $\min f(K)$.